# searching through subsets, algorithm (optimal or heuristic)

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, set-theory

I’m looking for help with search algorithm for a problem. The problem can be simplified to the following.

We have an object that can take certain attributes – X1, X2 … XN. N is of the order of 5000. However a particular object takes a subset of these attributes say Xi .. Xj (about 50).

A configuration is a particular subset of the attributes. There are certain configurations, numbering Z (order of 0.1 million), that are optimal.

Input:

```
Configuration 1: X1, X2, X3.. Xf
Configuration 2: X4, X6, X7, .. Xz
:
:
Configuration Z: X10, X200… XN
```

Problem: Given a certain object, ALPHA with a subset of attributes {Xi…Xj} the goal is to find the configuration that is closest to this object. The configuration can be a superset of the object ALPHA’s configuration. It could also be that no configuration has all of ALPHA’s attributes. Closest is defined as the configuration that has the most number attributes of ALPHA.

The naïve solution I have basically does the following

```
1. Take each configuration
2. Loop through each attribute of ALPHA
3. Keep track of the configuration with maximum number of matches to ALPHA
4. Pop out the configuration maximum matches.
```

I think the naïve solution is correct, however it is too slow. Is there an efficient way to do the search across the configurations? Even approximate heuristic is fine if it is very fast.

Adding C++, Java tags to see if there is software that does this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a better non-heuristic approach.  Store your optimal configurations in reverse.  *ie* mapping each attribute to the configurations it appears in.  *eg* (unrelated to your your example)

```
X1 : C1 C4 C5 C99999
X2 : C1 C2
X3 : C1
X4 : C1 C2
...
XN : C100 C200 C300
```

Now, you make an array of length `Z` to store how many matches you found.  You iterate through ALPHA, and for each attribute you go through the associated configurations.  For each configuration, you add one to the corresponding position in your array.

Finally, you run through the array and select the configuration with the largest count.  You could keep a running maximum instead if you like, but that would only be more efficient if you expected to do fewer than Z comparisons in total (number of elements in ALPHA multiplied by the average number of associated configurations).

This will find the best match, and ought to be about 50 times faster than your naive solution.

Comment: Thanks paddy. Your solution intuitively makes sense. I will have to think through in the morning :-). In the smaller test cases it did run about 10-20 times faster. Will run the bigger tests tomorrow and accept your answer.

Comment: No worries.  Good luck.  I suggested a speedup of 50x based on the typical numbers you mentioned, assuming that the configurations are evenly distributed across this space.  That might not be the case, but it should still be a lot faster.

Comment: Great news!!. Program is roughly 25 times faster. Thanks so much paddy.